# boost ASIO async_read_until doesn't compile with ASIO ssl client example

Tags: c++, ssl, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

Starting from [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp), I wanted to replace `async_read()` with `async_read_until()`.

So I looked up [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp), and saw how `async_read_until()` is called. And I saw that it's called as follows:

```
      boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, "\r\n",
      boost::bind(&client::handle_read_status_line, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

So the only difference I see compared to the SSL client example is that `response_` is a `boost::asio::streambuf`. So I created that object in my class body the same way, and then in the SSL client example, I replace the callback function:

```
  boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
      boost::asio::buffer(reply_, bytes_transferred),
      boost::bind(&SSLClient::handle_read, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

with the other function, and removed the `bytes_transferred` part. And it became:

```
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, response_, "\r\n",
        boost::bind(&SSLClient::handle_read, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

But... this doesn't compile. It gives me these errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from SSLClient.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:14:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of 'struct boost::_bi::result_traits<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (SSLClient::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int)>':
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:15:48:   required from 'class boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (SSLClient::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<SSLClient*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >'
SSLClient.h:99:51:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:69:37: error: 'void (SSLClient::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int)' is not a class, struct, or union type
     typedef typename F::result_type type;
                                     ^
In file included from main.cpp:14:0:
SSLClient.h:87:70: warning: unused parameter 'bytes_transferred' [-Wunused-parameter]
     void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
                                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:767,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from SSLClient.h:6,
                 from main.cpp:14:
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/read_until.hpp: In instantiation of 'typename boost::asio::async_result<typename boost::asio::handler_type<WriteHandler, void(boost::system::error_code, long unsigned int)>::type>::type boost::asio::async_read_until(AsyncReadStream&, boost::asio::basic_streambuf<Allocator>&, const string&, ReadHandler&&) [with AsyncReadStream = boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >; Allocator = std::allocator<char>; ReadHandler = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (SSLClient::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<SSLClient*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >; typename boost::asio::async_result<typename boost::asio::handler_type<WriteHandler, void(boost::system::error_code, long unsigned int)>::type>::type = void; std::string = std::basic_string<char>]':
SSLClient.h:99:52:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/read_until.hpp:707:3: error: static assertion failed: ReadHandler type requirements not met
   BOOST_ASIO_READ_HANDLER_CHECK(ReadHandler, handler) type_check;
   ^
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/write.hpp:615:3: error: no match for call to '(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (SSLClient::*)(const boost::system::error_code&, long unsigned int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<SSLClient*>, boost::arg<1> (*)()> >) (const boost::system::error_code&, const long unsigned int&)'
   BOOST_ASIO_WRITE_HANDLER_CHECK(WriteHandler, handler) type_check;
   ^
Makefile:472: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
13:14:05: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project GNOMEClientCmd (kit: Qt 5.4.1)
When executing step "Make"
13:14:05: Elapsed time: 00:04.
```

All I had to do to get all these errors, is just switch from `async_read` to `async_read_until` as explained. If I go back to `async_read`, it compiles fine. What am I doing wrong?

If you require any additional information, please ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Q. What Am I doing wrong

You're ignoring the documentation.

The documentation will tell you that `async_read-until` takes a streambuf¹, for one, and [`ReadHandler`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ReadHandler.html) requires the `bytes_transferred` placeholder still.

---

¹ just noticed you described that in the prose; It works a lot better to show the relevant code. Prefer [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) on SO

Comment: Actually you made me notice that I forgot to remove the `bytes_transferred` placeholder in the callback function. I removed it and it compiled. Honestly this is the worst thing ever in callback functions. Their debugging is a nightmare and very not clear. There's no clear indication to what the problem is, and one has to just speculate and imagine... I wish there's a better way to debug callback functions. Thank you.

Comment: Well. To be honest, I don't I deserve your rant. If you have a capable compiler, just use lambdas. It's not even the Asio stack here (it does have callback concept assertions) it's just the bind barfing. You don't need the bind with a lambda. _Help your compiler help you_

Comment: Sorry pal, it's not a rant. I'm very thankful for your try to help. I'm just complaining about how annoying it's because it's a trivial issue and I couldn't notice it because of the huge report from the compiler as errors that are far away from the real problem. It's has nothing to do with you :-) Thanks for the suggestion of lambdas, I'll consider it.